# Custom Handler not added to own Logger

Tags: java, logging, jboss7.x

i'm using a JBoss 7.1 and want to use a Custom Handler as a Module. The Problem is that the Handler is not added to my logger.

---

standalone.xml:

```
   ...

   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">

   ...

      <custom-handler name="CUSTOM" class="my.company.logging.handler.MyHandler" module="my.company.logging.handler">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </custom-handler>

        ...

        <logger category="my.company">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CUSTOM"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>

        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>

    ...
```

---

A Demo Class using org.jboss.logging.Logger:
( The example class from the Quickstarts: "jboss-as-log4j" )

```
    package my.company.logging.test;

    @SessionScoped
    @Named
    public class LogDemo implements Serializable {

    private final Logger logger;

    private String text;

    public LogDemo() {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void log() {
        logger.info(this.getText());
        this.setText(null);
    }
}
```

---

In this way no Logs will be send to my Handler.

I also tried to add the Handler to the RootLogger but than it works for all Log but not for the Logs from my own Logger.

Does anybody know what the Problem could be?

Greets
Martin

---

edit:

MyHandler:

```
package my.company.logging.handler;

public class MyHandler extends Handler {

    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private DB db;

    public MyHandler() {
        System.out.println("new MyHandler");
        if (connect()) {
            System.out.println("Mongo connected!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Mongo not connected!");
        }
    }

    private boolean connect() {
        try {
            this.mongoClient = new MongoClient();
            this.db = mongoClient.getDB("TestLogging");
            return true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        mongoClient.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(record.getLoggerName());
        final BasicDBObject logRecord = new BasicDBObject("message",
                record.getMessage());

        logRecord.put("level", record.getLevel().toString());

        Object[] parameters = record.getParameters();
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
            logRecord.put("Parameter" + i, parameters[i].toString());
        }

        System.out.println("...");
        String result = collection.insert(logRecord).getError();
        if (result != null)
            System.out.println("something went wrong: " + result);
        else
            System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

Note:
When i add this Handler to the Root Logger in the standalone.xml it works for each Module exept my own war.

Does the config only works with modules in JBoss or should it also works with war's?

Comment: Can you add your handler source here? The configuration looks correct.

Comment: I've added the source.

Comment: Did i need any Dependency in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Comment: Yes a custom handler requires it to be a module and the handler cannot be in your deployment.